# SUM datatable column with compute but NO filter

Tags: asp.net, datatable, sum

this seems to work when i put an item in it to filter, but i don't want to add a filter, ie just happy to sum the column and that's it.

i've tried passing in string.empty and "" but no joy:

```
object objColTotal;
objColTotal = _dataSetDataTable.Compute("Sum(Price)", "");
decimal tot = Convert.ToDecimal(objColTotal);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An empty string should work.

You can always use a filter that you are certain will include all your records.

---

Quick test on a Decimal column:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("DecCol1", typeof(decimal));
dt.Columns.Add("StrCol1");
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1.1, "r1"});
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2.2, "r2" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3.3, "r3" });

object sum = dt.Compute("SUM(DecCol1)", "");
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

I get the correct answer: 6.6

Comment: the column is of datatype decimal. i wonder if that will cause issues or if there is a way to deal with that?

Comment: @Dkong I don't think so; I ran a quick test and it worked for me.

Comment: thank for you help Jay. I thought I was going insane it kept bringing back zero, but it was a long list of values in the column with -ive and +ive values which totaled zero.

Comment: @Dkong Everybody needs a sanity check now and again. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

note 2 things

- if your column name **have space** you must use brackets and single or double quotation is not accepted.
- also note that Compute returns an object which upcasting it with something (int) **gives an error** and you must use other methods like the samples below

samples:

```
int Dones = int.Parse(dt.Compute("sum(Done)", "").ToString());
int InProgresss = int.Parse(dt.Compute("sum([In Progress])", "").ToString())
```